# How to make this drop down change the value after selecting another option in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, buefy

We are trying to select another item from drop down options but it doesn't changing the value:

```
     <b-dropdown aria-role="list">
        <b-button
          icon-right="caret-down"
          class="dropdown"
          size="is-small"
          slot="trigger"
        >
          <span>{{selectedProduct}}</span>
        </b-button>
<b-dropdown-item
          v-for="product in products"
          :key="product.id"
          aria-role="listitem"
          @click="setItem(selectedProduct)"
          v-model="selectedProductTag"
        >
          {{ product.name }}
        </b-dropdown-item>
      </b-dropdown>

**js part**

    editProduct(){
    ...
    ...
        this.selectedProductTag = {
          id: selectedProductId,
          name: product.name,
          tag: product.tag,
        };
    
    }

  setItem(selectedProduct) {
      this.selectedProduct = selectedProduct
    },
```

How to make it change both the selected option labels as well as v-model object data?

Comment: Its not an issue it's just not selecting another option and not changing value. Code is too large for making sandbox.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

I see you're using a `bootstrap-vue` component, but, for what you're doing, I would suggest you to use the [select](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select) component instead. But anyways, using the `dropdown` component:

**In your HTML**

```
<b-dropdown aria-role="list" v-bind:text="(selectedProduct.id == 0? 'Select here' : selectedProduct.name)">
  <b-dropdown-item
    v-for="(product, index) in products"
    :key="index"
    aria-role="listitem"
    @click="setItem(product)"
  >{{ product.name }}</b-dropdown-item>
</b-dropdown>
```

**In your `data` section**

```
data() {
  products: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "test1",
      value: 1,
      etc: "..."
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "test2",
      value: 2,
      etc: "..."
    }
    //....
  ],
  selectedProduct: {
    id: 0,
    name: "",
    value: 0,
    etc: "..."
  }
  //Make sure not to set selectedProduct to `null`, as it could result on an error
}
```

**In your `methods` section**

```
setItem: function(product) {
  this.selectedProduct = product;
},
```